# What is a CFM-based application?

Tags: terminology

When reading up about [Mac OS X Kerberos Extras](http://web.mit.edu/macdev/KfM/Common/Documentation/osx-kerberos-extras.html) while trying to get Kerberos working, I came across the phrase 'CFM-based application'. What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code Fragment Manager (CFM) based applications are, to the best of my knowledge, Carbon applications for OSX that were cross-compatible between OSX and Classic (9).

Found some more info [on this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rick_schaut/carbon-vs-cocoa) under **Executable Formats**.

Comment: Carbon...Framework.....Munging? What does CFM stand for?

Comment: Code Fragment Manager? That's a doozy.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I have come across CFM is in regards to the Cold Fusion rapid application development system. The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ColdFusion) article gives a decent overview of the platform.